# Resque plugin's resque-web is not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am using Resque and Resque scheduler, but when I enter the command `resque-web` it is not running. Instead prompting an error:

> bash: resque-web: command not found
>   So how to start this resque-web on my local server.

Comment: have you gem/bin on your path ?

Comment: It may help to know what command you are issuing.  You should be able to issue either `resque-web` or `bundle exec resque-web`. Once you issue this command, you should see text like in kbighorse's answer. See my comment for directions for navigating to the web interface's page.

Comment: I had to use bundle exec because resque was installed as a gem via bundler for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably trying to open the default browser and failing to do so. Try using:

**$ resque-web -L**

Answer (score 4):

```
$ bundle exec resque-web  
[Wed Jan 19 22:10:38 +0000 2011] Starting 'resque-web'...  
[Wed Jan 19 22:10:38 +0000 2011] trying port 5678...  
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Anyone know what I should try?  I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.1 and would like to get this working in nginx 0.8.53.

Comment: After issuing that command, did you try `ps aux | grep resque-web` to see if resque-web is actually running?  Also: you will be able to point your browser to http://192.168.1.1:5678/overview where "192.168.1.1" is your i.p. address. This is shown in the console where you issued the "rails server" command.

Comment: i also had the same problem. resque-web is doesn't fire browser but entering 127.0.0.1:5678 in browser loads the resque-web sinatra app. Any idea why this is happeing?

Comment: @ Gagan, are you assuming that issuing `resque-web` from within the console is going to open a browser for you? Issuing `resque-web` or `bundle exec resque-web` will start up an instance of resque-web, it's up to you to open a browser and enter the correct address.

Comment: This run with me
$ bundle exec resque-web -L

Answer (score 3):

bundle exec resque-web if its installed using bundler, it may also perhaps not be in your PATH .Try checking your path variables and locating resque-web.